# How to match strings that have exactly 2 slashes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a database with a lot of paths, and I need to find all the paths that have only 2 levels, not more not less.
For example, I need a query that will find string matching the following structure:

```
folder/folder/file.ext
```

But not:

`folder/file.ext` and not `folder/folder/folder/file.ext` or anything longer

My guess here is to use REGEX and match strings that precisely have 2 slashes `/` but I don't know how to formulate the expression, something like:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE `name` REGEXP '????'
```

In my case I need to find 2 slashes and is very specific but ideally this answer will be useful for anybody looking for 3 or X number of slashes or any other character repeated on the string.

Comment: What about `/folder/file.txt`? That has two slashes but only 1 dir, or will you never have leading slashes?

Comment: Maybe, in that case I'll look for 3 slashes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest method uses `like`:

```
where name like '%/%/%' and
      name not like '%/%/%/%'
```

Doing this as a regular expression is tricky.  But here is another method:

```
where length(name) - length(replace(name, '/', '')) = 2
```

As a regular expression:

```
where name regexp '^([^/]*[/]){2}[^/]*$'
```

So it is possible, although perhaps less scrutable.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE LENGTH(name) = 2 +
      LENGTH(REPLACE(name, '/', ''))
```